# How do I have a program create its own variables to match (up to an infinite) amount of user inputs?

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Study {

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Hello, welcome to Study Help v1.0!");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2500);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("In this program we will help you study for an upcoming test or assessment!");
    System.out.println("Unfortunately, this version only works for a multiple choice test.");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2500);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Please input the number of questions that there will be for your studying.");

    int questions;

    Scanner userNumber = new Scanner (System.in);

    questions = userNumber.nextInt();

    System.out.println("You've chosen " + questions + " questions.");
    System.out.println("Now, add the questions to your study guide.");

    //This will later become a while loop (until their input numbers equal the amount of questions they said earlier)
    System.out.println("Input the full question number " + (questions-=questions-1)+ " now.");

    String userInput;

    Scanner userQuestion = new Scanner (System.in);

    userInput = userQuestion.nextLine();
    }
}
```

I need to be able to assign every single question input to a new variable (questionOne, questionTwo, etc.). I would do the same thing for the answers and store both (questions and answers), in separate arrays.

Comment: Your last three words ("in separate arrays") answer the question don't they?

Comment: No, you're missing the point. That doesn't really have to do with my question. My question was asking how you can store an unlimited amount of variables assigned to user inputs WITHOUT predefining them. Thanks for looking at my question anyways though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Javas `ArrayList` Type. You can store many Objects at runtime withe the `list.add(obj);` Method. This way you can store as Many questions as you like!

Comment: so could I do something along the lines of list.add(user input is here) to add their input to an array?